# Scipy: Convert RGB TIFF to grayscale TIFF and output it on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb, grayscale

I want to manipulate **RGB** bands in a TIFF file and output the **grayscale** map on matplotlib. So far I have this code, but I couldn't get it on grayscale:

```
import scipy as N
import gdal
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

tif = gdal.Open('filename.tif')

band1 = tif.GetRasterBand(1)
band2 = tif.GetRasterBand(2)
band3 = tif.GetRasterBand(3)


red = band1.ReadAsArray()
green = band2.ReadAsArray()
blue = band3.ReadAsArray()

gray = (0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue)

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.imshow(gray)
pylab.show()
```

And these are the arrays:

```
[[255 255 255 ..., 237 237 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 237 237 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 237 237 251]
 ..., 
 [237 237 237 ..., 237 237 251]
 [237 237 237 ..., 237 237 251]
 [242 242 242 ..., 242 242 252]]

[[255 255 255 ..., 239 239 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 239 239 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 239 239 251]
 ..., 
 [239 239 239 ..., 239 239 251]
 [239 239 239 ..., 239 239 251]
 [243 243 243 ..., 243 243 252]]

[[255 255 255 ..., 234 234 250]
 [255 255 255 ..., 234 234 250]
 [255 255 255 ..., 234 234 250]
 ..., 
 [234 234 234 ..., 234 234 250]
 [234 234 234 ..., 234 234 250]
 [239 239 239 ..., 239 239 251]]
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: What are `band1Array, band2Array, band3Array` for, they aren't referenced.  The _formula_ to grayscale looks right.

Comment: @lukecampbell well, this tiff file is made of 3 bands, R,G & B so, band1Array, band2Array and band3Array are just to convert these bands into arrays.

Comment: is not that what you have used for `red` `green` `blue` ?

Comment: @lukecampbell oops, thanks for the catch! I copied the wrong thing, haha. Edited.

Comment: The last two lines should be `pyplot.imshow(gray, cmap='gray');pyplot.show()`. Works for me.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have gdal installed, but a similar approach using PIL looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

img = Image.open("/Users/travis/Desktop/new_zealand.tif")

img.getdata()
r, g, b = img.split()

ra = np.array(r)
ga = np.array(g)
ba = np.array(b)

gray = (0.299*ra + 0.587*ga + 0.114*ba)

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.imshow(img)
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.imshow(gray)
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.imshow(gray, cmap="gray")
```

It may be a simple matter of setting the color map to something besides the default ("jet") to get what you want, but I'm not sure what you're seeing.

Here are the images that are generated (don't ask me why the original is upside-down -- not sure what causes that):

[image: first figure]

[image: second figure]

[image: third figure]